# Pass PHP select option box values to another page

Tags: php, mysql

what i'm trying to doing is when user click on php select option.then
it's value should pass to another page as variable.

there is a code i'm
trying.

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("member")or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,ugroup FROM ugroups"); 

?>

<select name='group' id='group' >
<?php 
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value=' . $line['ugroup'] . '>' . $line['ugroup'] . '</option>';

}?>
</select>
<a href="db_sql/add_group.php?val=<?php echo $line['ugroup'];?>">click </a>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

this is add_group.php code

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();
    include('../limoconfig.php');
    if(!isset($_SESSION['adminuserid']) )
    {
        header('Location:../index.php');
    }
    else
    { 
    if($_GET)
    {
        $ugroup = $_GET['ugroup'];
        /*$id = $_GET['id'];*/

        $acc_status = "update users set ugroup='".$ugroup."' where id=1931";
        echo $acc_status;
        $rate = db::getInstance()->exec($acc_status); 
        header('Location:../home.php'); 
    } 

    }
    ?>
```

it's not working.

Comment: Is your goal to stay on the same page? Or is it to go to the next page? Your goal remains unclear.

Comment: i want to go next page with variable.

Comment: Ajax is best solution. As well as you have also submit the form on change event of select box. Make sure you must have write desire page name in form action

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to put your table within  
and then you can call ajax on click of your anchor ().

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var data='';
$("#group option:selected").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('value') !== '') {
        data=$(this).attr('value');
    }
});
$("a").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function() {

            $('body').css("opacity", "0.3");
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('body').css("opacity", "1");
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: He needs to include Jquery with your code ;) you might wanna add that too in your answer ;) I would also define an ID for your click event, cause it will completely go berserk on other anchor links.

Comment: can you include this for my code.please.i'm new to web development

Answer (score 0):

you can either do it with ajax or just using html forms.

eg of ajax : Just a simple eg, you can modify according to your need

```
<html>
<head>

function myAjax(str)
{

if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","add_group.php?ugroup="+str,true); // your next page

xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("group").value;
     myAjax(x);
}

    </script>

</head>
<body>


<table>
<tr><td>
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("member")or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,ugroup FROM ugroups"); 

?>

<select name='group' id='group' >
<?php 
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value=' . $line['ugroup'] . '>' . $line['ugroup'] . '</option>';

}?>
</select>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">click </a>



</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="results"> <!-- the echo of add_group.php gets displayed here --> </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have add it to my question

Comment: do you want to display result on 1st page only or on add_group.php page..?

Comment: when user select group from selection and click on "click" values should pass to add_group.php.in add_group.php should update the user group and redirect to home.php.please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a form tag and create a submit button instead of the link and it can send it in either POST or GET.

> The  element is a form control and can be used in a form to collect user input.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp